# Ubuntu Gnome disable / hide AppMenu

Tags: 14.04, gnome, appmenu, appearance, gnome-shell-extension

Lately, I installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 in a virtual box to check it out, I am new to Gnome 3 and I was not comfortable with the stanard behaviour of it. I wanted it to be more Gnome2-ish, but I like how the desktop looks - its not too bad for a Linux, where most desktop managers don't look so very pleasing. Anyway, disabeling the App Menu in the Gnome Tweak Tool doesn't solve my problem after all and the Shell extensions that would do what I want simply are not compatible with Gnome 3.14 anymore, since it should be possible with the possibilities Tweak Tool offeres from 3.10 onwards. Is there anybody here who could help me?

Greetings Friedrich

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: If you wanted a look like gnome 2 you could try ubuntu mate.

Comment: Hi xangua, I already tried Mate in Linux Mint Mate, but thank you for your suggestion. I'd still appreciate an answer to my question, I'd already be pleased if what I asked could be solved.

Comment: @the_Seppi: No, its no duplicate. I'm well aware of all these other desktop environments, but I dont look for them. I am looking for a way to hide / disable the AppMenu (the Display of the currently active window in the top bar as I already have that in the bottom bar). Any help in this concern would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an gnome extension called YAWL that shows icons on the top bar and it has an option to hide the app menu.

The problem with this extension is that the icons that it shows on the top bar are ugly - just like the app menu.

Here is the link to YAWL if you want 
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/674/yawl-yet-another-window-list/